# Globally increasing constants in C

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a series of global events that are used within a C program in different areas. Any area can create an arbitrary event to hook and handle appropriately.
I need a way to define a variable amount of arbitrary constants that are unique and global. Sanitation aside, this is approximately what I was hoping would work:

event_handler.h

```
extern int last_event_ = 0;

#define NEW_EVENT() (last_event_++)
```

first_handler.h

```
#define FIRST_EVENT NEW_EVENT()
```

second_handler.h

```
#define SECOND_EVENT NEW_EVENT()
```

main.c

```
#include "first_handler.h"
#include "second_handler.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Second event number: %d\n", SECOND_EVENT);
    printf("Second event number: %d\n", SECOND_EVENT);
    return 0;
}
```

This does not work as expected however because of the way macros are executed. Causing it to print out 0 then 1 when it should be printing out the same number.

Comment: do you want an `enum`?

Comment: I want a very arbitrary number of constants, so an enum is far too restrictive.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when first_handler.h is #included from multiple source files? Generate a different number each time, or the same one?

Comment: FIRST_EVENT should be the same for all included. Is this even possible?

Comment: statics are zero-initialized. just give each event its own static variable. assign it only if zero.

Comment: Note that `extern int x=0;` causes undefined behaviour if you include that file from more than one `.c` file - it should be `extern int x;` with one `.c` file providing a definition. (Although that still doesn't help with your problem).

Comment: @Alphadelta14 as you have described it, an `enum` satisfies your conditions. Doing `enum { FIRST_EVENT, SECOND_EVENT };` would print the same number in both cases in your sample code.  If the enum is not suitable, please update your sample code and description to show a situation where the enum does not do what you want.

Comment: I don't know why you want macro, inline function should do the same job

Comment: @Alphadelta14 It's not possible with a simple approach like this unless you only need this within one compliation unit (source code file). If you compile 1 source code file that defines the values  1,2 and 3, and then compile another file the next day, the compiler is not going to know that you've generated 1,2,3 yesterday and that it should start at 4 now, when compiling another file.

Comment: the value is being incremented every time the macro is invoked and the code is invoking it twice, so naturally it is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be done with [`__COUNTER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)  predefined macro.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want a set of counters you can increase and read.

Possible solution: create a family of global variables with a common prefix in the name; and handle them with macros. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EVENT_VAR(name) (EVENT ## name)
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name) int EVENT_VAR(name)
#define DECLARE_EVENT(name) extern DEFINE_EVENT(name)

#define EVENT_HAPPENED(name) (++ EVENT_VAR(name))

// in one of the compilation units:
DEFINE_EVENT(first);
DEFINE_EVENT(second);

// in header first_handler.h:
// DECLARE_EVENT(first);


int main() {
    EVENT_HAPPENED(first);
    EVENT_HAPPENED(first);
    // EVENT_HAPPENED(frist);  // compile-time checked
    printf("%d %d\n", EVENT_VAR(first), EVENT_VAR(second));
}
```